# BigQuery and Standard SQL: aggregate per distnict field in array

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to calculate the sum of traffic (in gbps), per district IP, for the sum of all the five-minute periods.

I am a newbie to BigQuery, so by looking at other examples, I tried the following:

```
WITH `project.dataset.test` AS (
  SELECT '01/01/2019 12:30' time, '192.168.10.1' ip_address, 10 network, 1 gbps UNION ALL
  SELECT '01/01/2019 12:30', '192.168.10.2', 11, 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT '01/01/2019 12:30', '192.168.10.3', 12, 3 UNION ALL
  SELECT '01/01/2019 12:35', '192.168.10.1', 10, 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT '01/01/2019 12:35', '192.168.10.2', 11, 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT '01/01/2019 12:35', '192.168.10.3', 12, 3 UNION ALL
  SELECT '01/01/2019 12:40', '192.168.10.1', 10, 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT '01/01/2019 12:40', '192.168.10.2', 11, 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT '01/01/2019 12:40', '192.168.10.3', 12, 3
  ),
ip AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT (ip_address) ip_address
  FROM `project.dataset.test`
),
qualified AS (
SELECT ip_address, network, ARRAY_AGG (gbps ORDER BY ip_address DESC LIMIT 1)[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] gbps
FROM `project.dataset.test`
GROUP BY ip_address, network
)
SELECT ip_address, network, SUM(gbps)gbps
FROM (
SELECT d.ip_address ip_address, network, ARRAY_AGG (gbps ORDER BY q.ip_address DESC LIMIT 1)[SAFE_OFFSET(0)] gbps
FROM ip d
JOIN qualified q
ON q.ip_address = d.ip_address
GROUP BY ip_address, network
)
group BY ip_address, network
ORDER BY gbps DESC
```

I expected the output to be:

```
Row     ip_address      network   gbps  
1       192.168.10.3    12        9
2       192.168.10.2    11        6
3       192.168.10.1    10        3
```

Instead, the actual output is:

```
Row     ip_address         network   gbps   
1       192.168.10.3       12        3
2       192.168.10.2       11        2
3       192.168.10.1       10        1
```

What am I doing wrong? How do select the sum of the distinct IPs, regardless of the number of 5-five minute periods and/or networks? Fyi, I have thousands of rows to sort through, this is just a sample I am working with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do select the sum of the distinct IPs, regardless of the number of 5-five minute periods and/or networks?

Below example is for BigQuery Standatd SQL

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.test` AS (
  SELECT '01/01/2019 12:30' time, '192.168.10.1' ip_address, 10 network, 1 gbps UNION ALL
  SELECT '01/01/2019 12:30', '192.168.10.2', 11, 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT '01/01/2019 12:30', '192.168.10.3', 12, 3 UNION ALL
  SELECT '01/01/2019 12:35', '192.168.10.1', 10, 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT '01/01/2019 12:35', '192.168.10.2', 11, 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT '01/01/2019 12:35', '192.168.10.3', 12, 3 UNION ALL
  SELECT '01/01/2019 12:40', '192.168.10.1', 10, 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT '01/01/2019 12:40', '192.168.10.2', 11, 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT '01/01/2019 12:40', '192.168.10.3', 12, 3
)
SELECT ip_address, network, SUM(gbps) gbps
FROM `project.dataset.test`
GROUP BY ip_address, network
```

with result

```
Row ip_address      network gbps     
1   192.168.10.3    12      9    
2   192.168.10.2    11      6    
3   192.168.10.1    10      3
```

Comment: Hi Mikhail, thanks for the reply. Apologies, I did not include one important detail..

I use this in my query to collect the data.  ```_PARTITIONDATE = DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 0 DAY)
    AND ip_capture_time >= TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 35 MINUTE)
    AND ip_capture_time <= TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 30 MINUTE)```

The query will select two 5-min periods, which is my original problem. Apologies, did not mention this. 

So, my original problem remains the same, i.e. how do I sum up the gbps for all the instances an IP shows up in both sets?

Comment: I am using this to format timestamp, which might explain why it is selecting data from two consecutive -minute periods:
  ```FORMAT_TIMESTAMP("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M",TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(DIV(UNIX_SECONDS(ip_capture_time),300) * 300), 'Europe/Lisbon') AS time,```

Comment: Hi Michail,

following the example above, my real data looks similar to this:

```Row time ip_address network gbps  
1 01/01/2019 12:30 192.168.10.3 12 3  
2 01/01/2019 12:35 192.168.10.3 12 3  
3 01/01/2019 12:40 192.168.10.3 12 3  
4 01/01/2019 12:30 192.168.10.2 12 3  
5 01/01/2019 12:35 192.168.10.2 11 2  
6 01/01/2019 12:40 192.168.10.2 11 2  
7 01/01/2019 12:35 192.168.10.1 10 1  
8 01/01/2019 12:30 192.168.10.1 10 1
9 01/01/2019 12:30 192.168.10.1 10 1```

Comment: It should collapse like this;

```Row time ip_address network gbps  
1 01/01/2019 12:30 192.168.10.3 12 9  
4 01/01/2019 12:30 192.168.10.2 12 6  
8 01/01/2019 12:30 192.168.10.1 10 3```